# Use JMeter to simulate receiving websocket broadcasts similar to okhttp3

Tags: websocket, jmeter, postman, okhttp

I'm working on Android application and we use okhttp3 to open websocket connection to our backend. There are 2 main websocket:

1. request-response mechanism for requesting information from backend.
2. subscribe mechanism for receiving broadcast or notify from backend.

The problem is I cannot simulate subscribe flow in JMeter and Postman. The flow in Android is

1. Login to the system using username-password through REST API, the server return token
2. Create new OKHttp Websocket Client
3. Send WebSocket Request to backend, tell them which message I want to subscribe.
4. Wait for the message from the backend.

Then I create test plan as follows:

1. [*CSV Data Set Config username*] Get username-password from .csv file
2. [*HTTP Login Request*] Calling REST API to login
3. [*WebSocket Open Info*] Open WebSocket Connection
4. [*WsSubscribeReq*] Send a message to backend telling the message code I want to subscribe (same format as the message used in Android).
5. [*WebSocket Single Read Broadcast*] Loop wait for incoming message.

[image]

I was running my Android application at the same time as I running JMeter, Android got the broadcast message but JMeter did not get any message.

How can I make this works?

Answer (score 0):

In its current form the question cannot be comprehensively answered so I can only give you a generic hint: given you send the same request you should be getting the same response.

1. Compare the requests originating from the Android application and JMeter using a [sniffer tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer).
2. Amend JMeter configuration so it would send exactly the same requests like Android application does
3. You should see the same behaviour

Pay attention to literally everything, URL query string, [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), payload which can contain [non-printing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-printing_character_in_word_processors)

It also worth [enabling JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the plugin by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
```

and checking server-side logs for any suspicious entries.